# Calculus: computation of $\sum \frac{2^i}{i!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, self-learning

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{2^i}{i!}$$

Would anyone mind telling me what is the answer? I know this may be a silly question but I would like to know.

Comment: What is the power series representation of $e^x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Maclaurin expansion of $e^x$ is:
$$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

So therefore:
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{2^i}{i!} = e^2 \approx 7.389$$